# Linked Lists and Throwing an Exception

Tags: java, linked-list

My question is about implementing a method `get(int n)` which should return the element at index n (indexing starts with 0). If the index is out of bounds, the exception `IllegalArgumentException` should be thrown.
This is the code I wrote, is it correct or should I change something?

(int size) for an array list

```java
public Item get(int size) {
        Node<Item> n= head;
        for (int i=0; i<=size;i++)
            n=n.next;

        if ( size < 0 ) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}       
        return null;*
```

Comment: Why throw `UnsupportedOperationException` when the task says you should throw `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: The best exception here would be the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the first check writing this at the start, before the loop:

```
if (head == null || size < 0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

And inside the loop you have to check if you fell outside the list:

```
if (n == null) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Finally, after the loop you have to return the actual element you found:

```
return n.getItem();
```

Also notice that `size` and `n` are confusing names for your variables, you'd be better off calling them `index` and `current`. Here's how the code should look like, taking into account all my recommendations:

```
public Item get(int index) {

    if (head == null || index < 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    Node current = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (current == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        current = current.next();
    }

    return current.getItem();

}
```

Comment: @Hanan did this post solve your question? if so, please don’t forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the checkmark to its left ;) . Also worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
public Item get(int size){
   if(head == null || size < 0){
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }
   else{
      Node n = head;
      for(int i=0; i <=size;i++){
         if(n == null){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
         }
         if(i != 0){
            n = n.next();
         }
      }
      return n.getItem();
   }
 return null;  
}
```

Comment: This can result in a `NullPointerException` when `size` is too big, but it should be a `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Exactly, here we go!

Comment: Assuming that the indexes are zero-based, this answer is not handling them correctly. And the method signature requires that an _item_ is returned, not a _node_. To see a correct solution, take a look at my answer.